# How to hide plus button in data and time picker in Android

Tags: android, datetime

I want to give permission to user, you have not select **future time and date**.

I want to make that is unable to pick data from the current time.How to how to hide plus sign if we add more time from the current time.

If Current time: May 8, 2013

```
+    +   +
May  8   2013
-    -   -
```

Now I want to click + sign, then then it is not activable. So how to code this. please give some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're asking multiple questions.

1. You want to make DatePicker a **required** input field
2. You want to make sure the user doesn't pick the initial default value, because this would imply that the user didn't even bother reading the form.
3. You want to make sure that the user inputs the date manually, instead of using the built-in buttons, because using buttons would make it too easy for the user to just click a button randomly a couple of times just to get rid of the form.

Am I correct?

If so, I'd suggest not even using DatePicker in the first place. There are other controls you can use to achieve the effect you're looking for.